# GUI application fails to launch as a systemd service(daemon) in user mode

Tags: systemd, services, gnome-settings-daemon

I have created a systemd service to run a Gui application in user mode.

This is my .service file located at ~/.config/systemd/user.

```
[Unit]
Description=daemon service in user session created for startup ways in linux

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/home/vipul.gupta/MyWorkspace
ExecStart=/home/vipul.gupta/MyWorkspace/GTKSource
Type=simple

[Install]
WantedBy=graphical-session.target
```

The Gui window appear if I use, `Environment=DISPLAY=:0` but I dont want to use it, as the service is running in user session, so it has access to display.

These are the logs:

```
Started daemon service in user session created for startup ways in linux
GTKTest[201583]: Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
GTKTest[201583]: cannot open display:
systemd[72001]: tallyuserdaemon.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
systemd[72001]: tallyuserdaemon.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

I m not able to figure out the reason.

Comment: "as the service is running in user session, so it has access to display", access, yes, but how will it know where that display is? You could also have multiple X or Wayland sessions going on too. That's why you need to specify where. Put it in the environment, make it read it from a file, whatever.

Comment: @muru oh,ok. should I be able to run GUI application in the system session in the same way?